Were those two questions about circular security really duplicates?
The question Does encrypting the key with itself make it easier to crack the ciphertext? was closed/merged with the question Encrypting a key with the same key using AES.
However, I do not see a reason to that, since the first question was much more general than the second one: In the first question, AES was cited only as an example (this is what "EG." in the first question stands for), while the second one was entirely about AES.
Moreover, the answers that the first question had received (Luis Casillas' answer and mine) not even cited AES, which means that anyone accessing the second question now will see a question solely about AES and two highly upvoted answers that do not discuss AES at all.

Even if these questions were not actually duplicates, they were merged and merges are irreversible (which is why they are a mod-only tool). Well, at least they're irreversible for mods.

The author had indicated that he saw it as a dupe, and if the answers fulfil the question then it is often considered a dupe. However, we can expand the question in such a way that AES is just an example. Would that satisfy your issues with this? I merged the answers so that they would stay even if the dupe would be removed, and to centralize the knowledge.

@MaartenBodewes I think that was a good workaround. Thank you for the edit you made there.

So did we conclude or decide anything about this situation? Is there still an issue?

@EllaRose when created this question on Meta.crypto I did not know that the merge was irreversible. So, given that and the edits made by MaartenBodewes, I think this issue is solved.

Would you like to post/accept that as an answer? That way readers of Meta will know that the issue is solved.

The author of the merged question agreed that it was a dupe in the sense that the answers fulfilled their question. However, the original question was just about AES, even if the answers were generic. 
First I merged the great answers on the dupe with the original question and then I've made the original question more generic. That way the answers were kept, and there is just one generic question left. Oh, and I upvoted the good answers, so in case anybody feels robbed of an accept, the difference should be minimal.
I hope that this is OK with all the parties involved.

If so, hit the accept so we can close this issue.
